# In App Purchase Verify Using Cloud Function

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, in-app-purchase

After Researching for last 24 hour i have found a very effective way to verify in app purchase but didn't get proper Information . I am looking to verify product purchase .

I tried to deploy the js file to firebase cloud function but showing i have error in `exports.validatePurchases = functions.database` method .   Can anyone please have a look on it and fix the error ?

Here is the code :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {google} = require("googleapis");
const publisher = google.androidpublisher('v2');
const authClient = new google.auth.JWT({
    email: '',
    key: '',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
});
admin.initializeApp();

exports.validatePurchases = functions.database
    .ref('/purchases/{uId}/{orderId}')
    .onCreate((event, context) => {
        const purchase = event.val();
        if (purchase.is_processed === true) {
            console.log('Purchase already processed!, exiting');
            return null;
        }
        const orderId = context.params.orderId;
        const dbRoot = event.ref.root;
        const package_name = purchase.package_name;
        const sku = purchase.sku;
        const my_token = purchase.token;

        authClient.authorize((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            publisher.purchases.products.get({
                auth: authClient,
                packageName: package_name,
                productId: sku,
                token: my_token
            }, (err, response) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                // Result Status must be equals to 200 so that the purchase is valid
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return event.ref.child('is_validated').set(true);
                } else {
                    return event.ref.child('is_validated').set(false);
                }
            });
        });
        return null;
    });
```

**The Error i have got while deploy :**

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        validatePurchases

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only functions:validatePurchases

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

In Firebase Function Log :

```
Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'googleapis'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message you get, and where you get it. In general, I recommend studying [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it really helps if you can isolate the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I got error In exports.validatePurchases = functions.database while deploying .

Comment: I have update my question and there is no proper guideline to solve the problem . Can you help me to solve the issue? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: What's the error you get? Just copy/paste it into  your question, so we can see it exactly.

Comment: I have added the error . @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, run cmd on Function Folder of your project :

Then, In order to add it as a dependency, run the following command:

```
$ npm install googleapis
```

Now Check if any functions are live on your project. If there are functions in the firebase console remove it. Now Try Deploy.